# how to get string values out of strings.xml and in to an arraylist [android]

Tags: java, android, xml, reflection

Pretty much I've been trying to figure this out for the past hour.
I want to generically get strings from `strings.xml` and in to my code so I can dynamically change the amount of strings without having to change anything in my code that loads them in to the array list.
So far all I have is

```
for(Field x :R.string.class.getFields())
        if(x.getName().startsWith("ans"))
            choices.add(/*what do I add here to get the string value from the field in to the arraylist */);
```

I can not figure out for the life of me how to get the string value out of the field object. All I am getting is either Id's [or at least what I think is an Id] or the name I've assigned it inside the `strings.xml` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    Resources res = getResources();
    for(Field x :R.string.class.getFields())
        if(x.getName().startsWith("ans")){
                int id = x.get(null);
                choices.add(res.getString(id));
            }
```

Comment: Yeah just had to change x.get(null) and cast it as an integer and surround with a try,catch

But it is the correct solution I was yearning for.

Comment: try {choices.add(res.getString((Integer) x.get(null))); } //this gets the id and then grabs the resource associated
    
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    catch (IllegalAccessException e){ e.printStackTrace();}
         }

Answer (score 1):

Create an XML file example.xml in res/xml folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
    <record name="foo" />
</data>
```

then parse it as shown below

```
XmlResourceParser xrp = context.getResources().getXml(R.xml.example);
try {
  int eventType = xrp.next();
  while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && xrp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("record")) {

      String name = xrp.getAttributeValue(null, "name");

      //choices.add(name);
    }

    eventType = xrp.next();
  }
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This is way too much effort. I wanted to use reflection. Faylons answer is the correct solution for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
 choices.add(getResources().getString(R.string.string1));
```

string1 is a string constant in strings.xml

Comment: Not generic enough. I want to add from a loop, not from a bunch of add() statements with the ID's hardcoded in, it causes maintenance issues.